# Multisite: How to get a list of installed languages

Tags: multisite, localization

In a network install there is a language setting which will let the super admin user install a language from a list of available languages.

How can I get a list of the **installed** languages? For example, en_US, hi_IN, hu_HU, ja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's [get_available_languages()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_available_languages/):

> Get all available languages based on the presence of *.mo files in a given directory.